# NullPointerException with dependency injection

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I am trying to use dependency injection for export to excel functionality provided by "Export Plugin"
It seems that whenevery I try to use service in my project i get error like following

```
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method export() on null object
    at pm.ProjectsController$_closure2.doCall(ProjectsController.groovy:39)
    at pm.ProjectsController$_closure2.doCall(ProjectsController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The code I am using is following, this just means service variable is null

```
def exportService// i have  tried with and without the initialization
        if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
            response.contentType = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=books.${params.extension}")

            exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,projectsList, [:], [:])
        }
```

It seems that no plugin that uses services is working in my project for example AsynchronousMailService in my project didn't work as it was suppose to and thus I have been using it like following

```
AsynchronousMailService asynchronousMailService = new AsynchronousMailService()
            asynchronousMailService.sendAsynchronousMail  {    
                to projectsInstance.projectLead.emailAddress
                subject "New project is assigned to you"
                html msg
            }
```

Unless I am missing somethig very basic I do not beleive I should be instantiating this class if the plugin offers the same as service.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you should never instantiate services or other Spring beans - use dependency injection. It might work, but if the bean has any dependencies of its own they'll be null since you're bypassing Spring.

You're not using dependency injection, you're declaring a local variable and expecting magic.

Dependency injection in Grails uses public fields. Since Groovy creates a public field into a getter and setter under the hood, Spring sees the setter and Grails is configured to inject by name, so as long as the field/setter matches a Spring bean name it works.

So your controller should look something like this:

```
class MyController {

   def exportService

   def myAction = {
      if (params?.format && params.format != "html") {
         response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
         response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                            "attachment; filename=books.${params.extension}")

         exportService.export(params.format,
                 response.outputStream,projectsList, [:], [:])
      }
   }
}
```

Note that I also removed the use of ConfigurationHolder since it's deprecated. The best way to get access to the config is from the `grailsApplication` bean. It's already injected in controllers (and taglibs), and in a service or other bean you'd just need a `def grailsApplication` field declaration.